# VBA Excel - Call Form and Form Object with variable instead of Actual Form / Object Name

Tags: excel, vba

Working in Excel VBA forms, I have two tree views, **treeview1** and **treeview2** in different forms

can i call and manipulate these treeviews from a variable instead of explicitly calling out "**Treeview1**" and "**Treeview2**".  For example if i create a "**treename**" and "**formname**"variable:

```
If TreeNumber = 1 Then formname = "UserForm1" treename = "TreeView1"
If TreeNumber = 2 Then formname = "UserForm2" treename = "TreeView2"

formname.treename.Nodes.Add Key:=dataID(i, 1) + CStr(i), Text:=dataID(i, 1)
```

instead of

```
if treenumber = 1 then
UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:=dataID(i, 1) + CStr(i), Text:=dataID(i, 1)
if treenumber = 2 then
UserForm2.TreeView2.Nodes.Add Key:=dataID(i, 1) + CStr(i), Text:=dataID(i, 1)
```

Comment: Try `Me.Controls("TreeView" & treenumber).Add ...`

Comment: Thanks Tim. The treeviews are are actually in different modules though, so is there a way to refer to different modules by variable? Instead of `Me.Controls(treename)...` I'd use a variable **FormName**, and code would be like `FormName.Controls(treename)...`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I missed the different userforms. Are the forms loaded?  If Yes maybe look at `UserForms(nameHere)`   Eg see: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/showanyform.htm